# play audio using in html5?

Tags: php, html5-audio

hi iam working on playing audio in website using html5 here is my code

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src='<?=$audiopath ?>'/>
</audio>
```

so audio play fine for only mp3 format audio's only but i need to play aac, m4a, AIFF, aax
also so any idea to play all this format's please guide me

Thanks for advance..

Comment: Convert your audio to the proper format server-side.

Answer (score 2):

http://jplayer.org/ 
See above link, its HTML5 with Jquery. Nice example.
Also http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/06/html-music-player/

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not support aac, m4a, aiff, aax etc. etc. etc.. Why do you need to support all those formats anyway?

If you *must* use those formats, you'll need a Flash object. Or an `<embed>` tag might work, maybe.

Comment: can you please tell me what format's support IE9 and crome,safari for audio

Comment: MP3 for the most part. Firefox is the main exception, as it refuses to support it and instead requires OGG.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> HTML5 browsers and their supported audio file formats:
>
> Firefox (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
> Safari (OSX, Win): MP3, M4A
> Mobile Safari iOS4 (iPad, iPhone, iPod): MP3, M4A
> Opera (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
> Chrome (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA, MP3, M4A
> IE9 (Win): MP3, M4A (Can install the WebM codec.)
> ```

taken from [here](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#reference-html5-audio-format)